# How to export PATH from within a called process

Tags: bash, shell, path, export, zsh

I've written a small `gradle-path` utility:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
export PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/Gradle/gradle-3.5/bin
```

But, when I call it from my shell, the PATH is not changed at the end.

The variable isn't set in the parent process if I understand correctly.

How to make that possible?

Comment: You have to source it; a process cannot affect the environment of its parent.

Comment: Thanks for your instructive comment -- had to remind this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As chepner said -

Executing it in its own subshell (normally) with something like

```
gradle-path
```

will create a child process, set the PATH in that child's environment, then deconstruct that environment when the child exits, doing *nothing* in the parent process's memory.

To change the PATH in the caller you have to run it in the caller's environment - "source" it - like this:

```
. gradle-path
```

or this:

```
source gradle-path
```

Those will basically insert the commands from the listed file into the caller's parsing stream, as if they had been written there.

Comment: Now that you both explain that, I know that I knew / had to know that; though, this escaped me somehow. Thanks for clearly answering this!